# List in Flutter app does not respond to touch events

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a simple app which is supposed to count number of taps on two buttons. I am trying to show that count using a row of icons. There are two types of icons : [icons.check](/questions/tagged/icons.check) and [icons.close](/questions/tagged/icons.close). This is the code I wrote:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Quizzler());

class Quizzler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: QuizPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [
    Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is where the question text will go.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                'True',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked true.
                scoreKeeper.add(
                  Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                'False',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked false.
                scoreKeeper.add(
                  Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //TODO: Add a Row here as your score keeper
        Row(
          children: scoreKeeper,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The list [scorekeeper](/questions/tagged/scorekeeper), is not getting updated when I press those two buttons. It is supposed to render new icons on the bottom of screen but in this case, it does not increase.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `setState` for every changes the UI;

```
onPressed: () {
  //The user picked false.
  scoreKeeper.add(
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  );
  // notifiy changes to UI
  setState((){});
},
```

Comment: My bad, rookie mistake. 
Thanks for answer.